# Cron jobs and daylight savings with EBS Worker and SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

I have various business level counters that get reset daily, weekly and monthly at midnight in my local timezone PST/PDT so needs to allow for Daylight Savings.

However, my EBS worker instance that loads the jobs into SQS from cron.yaml is executing them in UTC despite the instance being configured as America/Los_Angeles.

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Beanstalk SQS worker uses UTC time to schedule work. All times are first converted to UTC before processing cron jobs. I would recommend changing the scheduled time of your cron jobs by deploying a new version of your app around the time the daylight savings time flip.

Please let me know if you have further questions.